# unexpected backtracking in simple prolog example

Tags: prolog

The following is a simple prolog program.

```
% parent facts
parent(john, jane).
parent(john, james).
parent(sally, jane).
parent(martha, sally).
parent(deirdre, martha).

% ancestor recursive definition
ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X,Y).
ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X,A), ancestor(A,Y).
```

Using SWI-Prolog, specifically swish.swi-prolog.org, the following simple query produces the correct answer **true**, but also appears to backtrack and then say **false**.

```
?- ancestor(john, jane).

true
false
```

This puzzles me, and is unexpected.

I tried tracing:

```
trace, ancestor(john, jane).
 Call:ancestor(john,jane)
 Call:parent(john,jane)
 Exit:parent(john,jane)
 Exit:ancestor(john,jane)
1true
 Redo:parent(john,jane)
 Fail:parent(john,jane)
 Redo:ancestor(john,jane)
 Call:parent(john,_696)
 Exit:parent(john,jane)
 Call:ancestor(jane,jane)
 Call:parent(jane,jane)
 Fail:parent(jane,jane)
 Redo:ancestor(jane,jane)
 Call:parent(jane,_698)
 Fail:parent(jane,_698)
 Fail:ancestor(jane,jane)
 Redo:parent(john,_696)
 Exit:parent(john,james)
 Call:ancestor(james,jane)
 Call:parent(james,jane)
 Fail:parent(james,jane)
 Redo:ancestor(james,jane)
 Call:parent(james,_698)
 Fail:parent(james,_698)
 Fail:ancestor(james,jane)
 Fail:ancestor(john,jane)
```

What puzzles me is that prolog seems to redo: `parent(john, jane)`. **Question: Why is this?**

My own (admittedly student) understanding is that prolog will only backtrack to try additional values for variables unbound at query time. Here there are no variables in the first rule of the recursive definition that are unbound at query time: `ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X,Y)`.

I could understand prolog trying new values for the variables in the second rule of the recursive definition: `ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X,A), ancestor(A,Y).` Here prolog could try new values for A.

---

UPDATE - I tried removing the recursive part of the definition:

```
ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X,Y).
% ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X,A), ancestor(A,Y).
```

The query still results in backtracking.

```
?- ancestor(john, jane).

true
false
```

.. although the trace is shorter.

```
trace, ancestor(john, jane).
 Call:ancestor(john,jane)
 Call:parent(john,jane)
 Exit:parent(john,jane)
 Exit:ancestor(john,jane)
1true
 Redo:parent(john,jane)
 Fail:parent(john,jane)
 Fail:ancestor(john,jane)
false
```

This focusses on the unexpected behaviour more sharply. Why does prolog backtrack to a point which has no **unbound** variables?

Answer (score 0):

This can be boiled down to:

```
parent(john, jane).
parent(john, james).
parent(sally, jane).
```

```
?- parent(john, jane).
true ;
false.
```

The choicepoint happens because there is no [index](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=jitindex) on the combination of both arguments.

The easiest way to solve this is to use [tabling](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=tabling), by adding to the code:

```
:- table parent/2.
:- table ancestor/2.
```

... which improves determinism.

Comment: I just tested this on https://swish.swi-prolog.org and I only get 'true' not 'true; false'. A screenshot is here https://imgur.com/a/qa1jpN5. I also tried the command line local version and it does the same, screenshot here https://imgur.com/a/66MJ5OH

Comment: Oops, please add the `sally` line also, for this small demonstration to work.

Comment: Thanks @brebs that now shows the behaviour you talk about. I am still puzzled - what is the benefit of prolog wasting time (and confusing users) with this counterintuitive behaviour. Without sally it doesn't backtrack, with sally it does. The database facts are not complex and don't seem to merit backtracking to explore some part of a resolution tree? I would be grateful if someone could explain WHY prolog is designed to do this. Also I checked gprolog and that does it too.

Comment: "Wasting time"? It is the opposite - Prolog is being efficient by presenting the first answer it finds, then "remembering its position" to efficiently search for alternatives if you ask it to. Just e.g. wrap in `once/1`, or end in `!`, if you know for sure that you only want the first solution. Embrace the flexibility of the potential for multiple solutions.