# unexpected prolog backtracking even in simple program

Tags: prolog

The following is a very simple prolog program.

```
parent(john, jane).
parent(john, james).
parent(sally, jane).
```

The following simple query results in prolog answering **true**, but also **false** after prompting for more answers.

```
?- parent(john, jane).
true ;
false.
```

**Question:** Why does prolog do this?

Swi-prolog, swish and gprolog all do this.

**Thoughts**

Prolog should be able to answer this question with simple unification, and exhaust the database of facts with no need to create a choice point. What is the "choice"?

My understanding is that choicepoints, for backtracking to, are created for variables that are not bound at query time. There are no variables here - none in the database of facts/rules, and none in the query.

A similar question (see below) resulted in comments suggesting indexing. I am no expert but that suggests a mechanism for prolog to internally store and search facts. Indexing resulting in a choice point feels like a failure in optimisation.

**Similar Question**

This question is a smaller, more focussed one, as a result of a previous question. The clarity resulting from the comments there merited this new question, to help focus the question and also help new readers.

[unexpected backtracking in simple prolog example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73847434/unexpected-backtracking-in-simple-prolog-example)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73847434/unexpected-backtracking-in-simple-prolog-example

Comment: Indexing is a critical topic in understanding why a choicepoint exists here. *Read* https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=jitindex . As in a SQL database, one would not index 3 data rows, because there would be no performance benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is that choicepoints, for backtracking to, are created for variables that are not bound at query time.

Choicepoints are created when the search tree branches and Prolog has to *choose* which branch to explore next. They are not tied to unbound variables, although they do affect variable binding, they are tied to the way it explores the search tree looking for answers.

> What is the "choice"?

Despite the code being abstract "logical relations" it really works through your code line by line from top to bottom - your code representing a root of a tree which branches three times for three `parent/2` predicates - and at the first branch it has found a valid answer to the query so it sets a choicepoint "I am here in the tree, and choosing this answer" and gives the answer to you.

```
parent(john, jane).  <-- *choose* this valid answer, wait for your input.
parent(john, james).
parent(sally, jane).
```

There are more branches, more `parent/2` predicates not checked, there might be more results hiding in those parts of the tree and it needs to *back up* to the root and then proceed down into the next `parent/2` branch to find out. It won't know until it looks, and it won't look until you ask it to. You could change the code to have two valid answers:

```
parent(john, jane).
parent(john, james).
parent(john, jane).
```

Then:

```
?- parent(john, jane).
true ;
true.
```

what would you expect this version to do in your approach?

NB. that the second `true` does not leave a choicepoint because all the `parent/2` predicates have been checked by then.

> Prolog should be able to answer this question with simple unification, and exhaust the database of facts with no need to create a choice point.

It can answer with simple unification. It doesn't search ahead of the current search point on the offchance that there might be no more answers, it's from the 1970s, that would be impossible for performance. Likely you could build a variant Prolog which did meet a choicepoint, spawn a second searcher to run ahead if the code falls below some simplicity cutoff point, wait for whether it finds more answers or runs out, before deciding whether to set a choicepoint - but then it wouldn't behave like Prolog behaves and ... what would be the benefit, what would you gain?
As you say, you can already [table predicates](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=tabling) to reduce searching and improve performance in certain situations.

Comment: Just to add to this, some prolog implementations will index predicates on the first term if it is an atom. That is, if you put `parent(sally, jane)` as the first fact then query `parent(sally, jane)` or `parent(sally, X)` then prolog will immediately eliminate  the `parent(john, ...)` facts and not leave a choicepoint (since there is only one `parent(sally, ...)` predicate).